# Error when try import Cisco scheme to OpenLDAP

Tags: linux, openldap

I'm trying to import the Cisco schema into my OpenLDAP server. I was followed one instruction where it is need to create a ldif file and after that use it to import. But when I ran the slapcat I face it this message:

```
594e80a3 /etc/openldap/schema/cisco.schema: line 89 objectclass: AttributeType not found: "sn"
slapcat: bad configuration directory!
```

Here my schema.conf:

```
include     /etc/openldap/schema/cisco.schema
```

When I put the `core.schema` it run but the file is empty.

Here is the command:

```
slapcat -f schema.conf -F . -n0 -H ldap:///cn={0}cisco,cn=schema,cn=config -l cisco.ldif
```

Can any one help me?

Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

`slapdcat` is likely the wrong utility. You probably ought to use `slaptest`.

You'll also need to include any dependencies that cisco.schema has.
`'sn' 'surname'` is part of `core`. `cosine` and `nis` (or `rfc2307bis`) are also common dependencies.

> -F confdir
>   specify a config directory.  If both -f and -F are specified, the config file will be read and converted to config directory format and written to the specified directory.  If neither  option  is  specified,  slaptest will attempt to read the default config directory before trying to use the default config file. If a valid config directory exists then the default config file is ignored. If dry-run mode is also specified, no conversion will occur.